# Snowflake : Error while running snowsql (Error: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for some help on the below error.
I just installed snowsql on my Mac and running the below command. But I keep getting the below error. Tried installing it multiple times. Appreciate any help on this.

snowsql is a binary, so I will not be able to any shebang line

```
/Applications/SnowSQL.app/Contents/MacOS/snowsql -v
[Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/rj/.snowsql/1.2.22/snowsql'



bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: which method did you use to install it?

Comment: I downloaded the dmg package from the below link for Mac and installed
https://developers.snowflake.com/snowsql/

Comment: @user141498 Did you ever find a solution for this?  Experiencing the same thing:
[Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/jamesmckeown/.snowsql/1.2.26/snowsql'

Answer (score 0):

set it at executable by running this in terminal :

```
chmode +x < snowsql>
```

Comment: Thank you, Eshirvana.
But it's not helping and I'm getting the same error.                                                  


chmod +x /Applications/SnowSQL.app/Contents/MacOS/snowsql
/Applications/SnowSQL.app/Contents/MacOS/snowsql
[Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/rajeshyarlagadda/.snowsql/1.2.22/snowsql'